Difference between edges definition in undirected graphs
I'm studying graphs for an algorithms course.
I saw two different definitions for edges of undirected graphs in different textbooks:

One defines an undirected graph as a couple of sets $(V, E)$ where V is the sets of the "nodes" and E is the sets of the "edges". Edges are defined as sets $\{u, v\}$ where $u, v \in V$ are nodes of the graph
The other one defines an undirected graph also as a couple of sets $(V, E)$ where V is the sets of the "nodes", but E is instead a symmetric relation $E \subseteq V^2$ so that edges are couples $(u, v)$ of nodes such that $(u, v) \in E \implies (v, u) \in E$

The main consequence I see of the difference between those two definitions is that the first doesn't allow self loops, while the second one does. Is there one which is more correct? Isn't "forbidding" self loops a problem, if you find yourself in a situation where you need them?

The first definition also allows loops, because $\{v,v\}=\{v\}$. It would forbid loops if you were selecting distinct $u,v$, for instance asking for $\{u,v\}\in\binom{V}{2}$.
In general, context is the answer. Sometimes, we want loops, sometimes we don't. We might want to allow multi-edges too, meaning you have several times the ``same'' edge in the graph. In that case $E$ is a multi-set, not a set.
In many cases we work on ``simple graphs'', meaning no loops and no multi-edges. You just need to be clear when you define your objects.

perfect, thank you
